# Extract the two first words of a string in bash

Tags: string, bash, extract

I have a string with a sentence within like 
`a="hello my dear friend"`. I want to retrieve the first two words (here it should be "hello my"), knowing that the number of words can vary. I tried `${a%% *}` but it only gives me the first one.

In the same kind, I need to extract the whole sentence without the two first words. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use BASH arrays for this:

```
# construct an array delimited by whitespace
a="hello my dear friend"
arr=($a)

# first two words
echo "${arr[@]:0:2}"
hello my

# anything after first 2 words
echo "${arr[@]:2}"
dear friend
```

Comment: A downside to this approach would be that you can't maintain whitespace in your string.

Comment: Yes but since OP says first 2 "words", words cannot have spaces

Comment: Yes, in my case this solution seems to be the better. But thanks for the tip with the whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the string into an array and use a slice:

```
$ read -ra words <<<"$a" && echo "${words[@]:2}"
dear friend
```

At the cost of another process, you could also use `cut`:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f3- <<<"$a"
dear friend
```

The behaviour of this is slightly different, as it splits on single spaces, whereas the approach using read will consume any number of spaces between each word.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to capture the portion of the text you want:

```
$ a="hello my dear friend"
$ [[ $a =~ ^([^ ]+ [^ ]+)\ ?(.*) ]]
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
hello my
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
dear friend
```

Bash's `extglob` feature might also work, using a matched expression as an exclusion:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ a="hello my dear friend. would you like a beer?"
$ b="${a#+(!( )) +(!( )) }"
$ echo "$b"
dear friend. would you like a beer?
$ echo "${a%$b}"
hello my
```

Or from the other end of the string:

```
$ c="${a% +(!( )) +(!( ))}"
$ echo "$c"
hello my dear friend. would you like
$ echo "${a#$c}"
 a beer?
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell functions work for this in any Bourne shell or later:

```
$ f2 () { echo "$1" "$2" }
$ frest () { shift; shift; echo "$*" }

$ a="hello my dear friend"

$ f2 $a
hello my

$ frest $a
dear friend
```

Comment: By dropping the quotes you are exposing yourself to all kinds of nasty surprises.